# Can I combine jQuery with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use the Javascript selector `document.querySelector` insted of `$` or `jQuery` jQuery selector but I want to combine the Javascript selector with jQuery functions (like `.getJSON()`, `.html()`, `.append()` , etc.).

For example:

```
$.getJSON("list.json", function(data) {
    document.querySelector("#content").html(data.name);
});
```

Here when I use the **document.querySelector** I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` and when I use **$** I don't get any error. 

<kbd>[jsFiddle Test](http://jsfiddle.net/g4ZZK/)</kbd>

Is it possible to run jQuery and Javascript together?

Thanks!

Comment: why you want to use both jquery has all options

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: if "jquery has all options", how do i get the text of the first HTML comment in the document?

Comment: You *can* do `$(document.querySelector("#content")).test(data.name)`, but it makes no sense. And won't work in browsers that don't support `querySelector`.

Comment: Of course you can mix both syntaxes - JS and jQuery. Sometimes pure JS is faster, e.g. using `this.id` is faster than `$(this).attr('id')`. Keep in mind that when mixing, code might get confusing. Either way, it's your personal choice.

Comment: @lesssugar jQuery has JS syntax. jQuery is just a library to deal with complicated tasks (although people are abusing jQuery nowadays). How could a library for a language suddenly have another syntax?

Comment: jQuery runs in more places than javascript, like ie7 (jScript)... if you want to be pedantic, even chrome (ecmaScript) doesn't support JavaScript.

Comment: @dandavis Godness, jQuery can't work without JavaScript!! IE7 has JavaScript by the way.

Comment: @dandavis Erm, jQuery **is** JavaScript, so that comment makes no sense...

Comment: @wumm: it works in ie7, which runs jScript, not javascript. there are only a few hundred differences between jScript and JavaScript, but they are not the same...

Comment: @wumm Agreed. However this "proxy" you're writing about seems to have different syntax to me (as in the tiny example I gave above). The outcome is the same, sure, the syntax for achieving it - is obviously not.

Comment: @lesssugar "The syntax of a computer language is the set of rules that defines the combinations of symbols that are considered to be a correctly document." [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_(programming_languages)) I don't think jQuery can change that.

Comment: @wumm: He talks about *selector* syntax. jQuery's Sizzle engine has extended the DOM selector spec. Both are embedded in JavaScript (or the various other ECMAScript implementations) as string literals.

Answer (score 5):

Off couse yes! It is possible to run jQuery and JavaScript together in you application.

All you need to know is, which is a JavaScript Object when trying to run some methods of it. jQuery can be handy sometimes. But, yes! You can work with them together.

Secondly, remember that jQuery is a JavaScript's Library. It isn't anything other than JS. To be simple, jQuery needs JavaScript to run. JavaScript doesn't need jQuery to run.

From this MDN source, it is stated that you can use that method just the way it is.

```
document.querySelector(".someclass");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector

All you now need to make sure is of that, that class you're trying to access **exists**.

Comment: Thank you so much! But the `document.querySelector` doesn't work with jQuery functions. Please see this test: http://jsfiddle.net/g4ZZK/

Comment: @Fuiba That's because many of jQuery's methods are properties on a jQuery object, and the way to get a jQuery object is to pass something to the `$`/`jQuery` function. A jQuery object is not an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element) object, which is what is returned by `querySelector()`. This is why Bergi suggested what he did in his comment (the fourth comment on your question that he mentions here), because that wraps the `Element` from `querySelector` in a jQuery object, thereby allowing you to now use many of jQuery's methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.getJSON("list.json", function(data) {
    $(document.querySelector("#content")).html(data.name);
});
```

PS:

But there isn't any sense to use it everywhere. Check the @afzaal-ahmad-zeeshan answer & read how to use native functional of DOM elements. jQuery isn't a panacea.

Answer (score 0):

jslayer's answer gave me an idea, which seems to work.
Wrapping js code in `$()` seems to work (though I'm not sure why).

For example, to use `slideToggle()` (which is only available in jQuery, I think), doing

```
event.target.nextElementSibling.slideToggle()
```

does not work, but

```
$(event.target.nextElementSibling).slideToggle()
```

does.